# Can I revert my PostgreSQL database to the state of a specific point in time?

Tags: postgresql

Can I revert my PostgreSQL database to the state of a specific point in time?

Let's say I have no proper backup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure [PITR](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html)  or use a tool for this like: [barman](https://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.15/), [wal-g](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g)